# model isn't working as expected C#

Tags: c#, model, mapping, dapper

My model is getting data I need, but I'm not sure how to organize it in the way I need. I have it where the model pulls a team, and a player. The issue is when mapping my data to the model it gives me duplicate teams, and doesn't allow me to call players individually. essentially I have a new object for each player, but I want a new object for each team instead, and without duplicates. I also want each team to have a player property where I can pull an individual player.

Here is what I have so far.

**Current method**

```
public HashSet<Player> getPlayers()

    {
        var myHashset = new HashSet<Player>();

        const string storedProc = "aProc";

        dynamic players;

        using (var conn = DBconnection.myConnection())
        {
        players = conn.Query(storedProc, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }

        foreach (var record in players)
        {
            var myPlayer = new Player
            {
                team = record.team,
                player = record.player
            };

            if (myPlayer != null)
            {
                myHashset.Add(myPlayer);
            }
        }
        return myHashset;
```

**Model**

```
public class Player
{
    public string team { get; set; }
    public string player { get; set; }

}
```

So in conclusion I need it to return an object that checks the data to see if the team is a duplicate. If it is then add the player to the team that currently exists. If it is a new team then create the team, and add the player.

**What stored Proc returns when executed in visual studio**

It returns a table that is laid out like this.

RowID --- player    ---     Team
1 --- roy      ---         bengals
2 --- nick      ---        bengals
3 --- jeff      ---         browns
4 --- carl      ---        steelers

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't copy and pasted from your actual application as there are a number of errors in the code which would mean it would not compile. The following line for example:

`myHashset.Add(player);`

Where does `player` come from? It does not exist in the current scope. I'm assuming you're meaning to add `myPlayer`?

Comment: no it isn't. sorry. I don't have the code on me at the moment, and just went to free hand it. I am out of town for the weekend, but wanna try and get this done by Monday if i can remote into my network. Aside from the edit correcting Punctuation though this should compile. I am using Dapper as an ORM. if that affects anything.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Sounds like a linq issue, not a problem with your model.

Comment: From the issue you describe I am going to guess the issue is with your stored procedure and not the code here. Try running the stored procedure in isolation on your database to see what data it returns.

Comment: @GaryEmery I added an edit to display what the stored proc would return if executed in management studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you review your model structure.

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Players { get; set; }
}
```

then in your loop

```
List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();

foreach (var record in players)
{
    Team team = teams.SingleOrDefault(q=>q.Name == record.team);

    if(team == null)
    {
         team = new Team();
         team.Name = record.team;
         team.Players = new List<string>();
         team.Players.Add(record.player);
         teams.Add(team);
    }
    else
    {
        team.Players.Add(record.player);
    }       
}
```

then return your list of teams (don't forget to change your method return type)

```
return teams;
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, and the logic makes sense. However after I implemented it I get 0 teams. When debugging I can see that everything is mapping where it should, but the code never hits the else statement, and never adds a team to the teams list.

Comment: Is there definitely items inside of your players variable? Sounds like your loop is not being iterated over.

Comment: I fixed it. It just needed to be added to the list in the for each loop. I suggested an edit to the answer for future people who view this thread.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments made on your question, I think the following may be helpful. However, for the record, none of this is best practice, and I can't professionally recommend other people do this. But it solves the issue you have with the constraints you're under.

If you just want to get the list of teams with no duplicates, you could do the following:

`List<string> teams = myHashSet.Select(x => x.team).Distinct().ToList();`

This will return a distinct list of teams. Essentially, if you want to get individual teams, and just pull through one player, you're going to have to manually go through your `HashSet` after you have built it up.

EDIT: Some information in the comments below the question itself have been removed (or I can't see them!) but alphamalle did mention that they do not have access to modify the stored procedure, hence my approach above.

Comment: I will try this ASAP, and come back to let everyone know if it fixed my issue.

Comment: It should set you on your way to solving the problem. If what you need is a list of teams, and then a list of players on that team, you may need to make the `player` property in your Player class a `List<string>` so you can add all of the players that are returned rather than just one.

Comment: I did attempt a list, but for some reason visual studio won't compile when I do this. It's possible I'm messing up the context when trying to add to the list in the current store object. @GaryEmery

Comment: Phil's answer is the full answer to your question. Mine will only get you a unique list of teams.